# Forcing web.config transforms on build in VS2012 / VS2013

Tags: asp.net, web-config, visual-studio-2013, transform

So our method of deploying web applications is that we (the developers) create MSI packages that the IIS guys extract the files and copy over.  Yeah, I know, but that's what we're stuck with.

Using VS2012 or VS2013, how in God's name do I get a web.config transform to happen on Build/Rebuild?  I'm currently using 2013 with the Visual Studio Installer extension, and every time I install the MSI I have the straight, untransformed web.config file.

We ARE allowed to publish to the Development server, and that works great - fully transformed web.config.

I added ConfigurationTransform, which yields:

```
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" />
```

But that's not working correctly, as I'm getting this in my Output:

```
_CopyAppConfigFile:
  Copying file from "Web.config" to "bin\SAOCDR.dll.config".
```

Which of course, is wrong.

Any guidance is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that this line:

```
Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config"
```

Needs to be:

```
Destination="$(OutDir)web.config"
```